# How to add url for SLComposeViewController in iOS7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, slcomposeviewcontroller

In my app i'm using `SLComposeViewController` to send tweets. I'm also calling its method `addURL:` like this:

```
[tweetSheet addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.com/apps/MyAppName"]];
```

and it works fine in iOS 6, but in iOS 7 it opens iTunesStore right after being presented on the screen. How do i fix it?

UPDATE:

```
 if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:network])
{
    AppController *appController = (AppController *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    MyNavigationController *navController = appController.navController;

    UIViewController *currentController = [[navController viewControllers] lastObject];

    SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:network];
    [tweetSheet setInitialText:text];
    [tweetSheet addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:temp_character]];
    [tweetSheet addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.com/apps/MyAppName"]];

    tweetSheet.completionHandler = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){

        [currentController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

        if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultDone)
          [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:HC_TWEET_SENT_NOTIFICATION object:nil];

    };

    [currentController presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Could you add all your code for the creation of the tweet sheet and when you present it ?

Comment: I just tried your code and it worked without problems. Try to store the boolean returned from `-addURL:` and log it to see if the link gets added

Comment: the boolean is YES. Did you try it in simulator? In simulator it works all right, but not on device

Comment: I tried it on both. Could you try with the url of another app (not the one in use).

Comment: it still opens iTunes no matter what app i use

Comment: I met with the same issue but hadn't find good solution

Comment: Hi am getting Settings page problem in IOS 7 how can i solve that issue

Answer (score 0):

Your custom socialIntegration class has a bug in it. It only returns a SLComposeViewController if Facebook is available on the device. If it isn't, it returns nothing.

However, you don't test for this when you actually call it:

```
SLComposeViewController * faceSheet=[self.socialIntegration showFacebook:@"text" andImage:nil andLink:@"link" andView:self];
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //[self netConnectionTrue:cell Connected:answer];
            //[tempAlertView show];
            [self presentViewController:faceSheet animated:YES completion:NO];

        });
```

...you're not checking to see if faceSheet is nil. So if there's no Facebook account you call presentViewController with a nil object, which triggers the error you're seeing.

The reason you are seeing this on iOS 7 is your linked FB accounts probably got reset, but it was probably a source of crashes for your users on iOS 6 as well.

Comment: It's about Twitter and he actually checks using `+isAvailableForServiceType:`

Comment: Hi am getting Settings page problem in IOS 7 how can i solve that issue